# How do I make calls to a boardgamegeek api using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api

I am calling www.boardgamegeek.com API.

I am using below code:

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/collection/dhasmain");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

    // List data response.
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("?own=1").Result; 
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var dataObjects = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
    }
```

But it is showing *Result=Not yet computed*.

Can anyone please suggest to me what the issue is?

I am also using the below code but it is not returning anything.

string dataObjects = "";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/collection/zefquaavius");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
      new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

```
    client.GetStringAsync("?own=1").ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        dataObjects = task.Result;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are calling the get asynchronously and not giving the call enough time for the call to complete when you access the result. You can use `ContinueWith` to respond to the call once the request is completed:

```
client.GetStringAsync("?own=1").ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        string dataObjects = task.Result;
    });
```

**EDIT:** Based on your comments, I see your UTF-8 encoding issue. The code below will handle the encoding issue so you have a string of XML from the response.

```
byte[] dataObjects = null;
client.GetByteArrayAsync("?own=1").ContinueWith(task => { dataObjects = task.Result; }).Wait();
string xmlResponse = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataObjects);
```

Comment: I am now using the following code but it is not returning anything.



 string dataObjects = "";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/collection/zefquaavius");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
      new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

        client.GetStringAsync("?own=1").ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            dataObjects = task.Result;
        });

Comment: If it's a simple app where you don't mind blocking the main thread you are on (and thus just want to run synchronously, you can add a Wait at the end, so `client.GetStringAsync("?own=1").ContinueWith(task => { dataObjects = task.Result; }).Wait();`. Then you know dataObjects will have the value after the Wait is called.

Comment: When I am calling the 
client.GetStringAsync("?own=1").ContinueWith(task => { dataObjects = task.Result; }).Wait();

It is giving the exception "system.aggregateexception was unhandled by user code"

Comment: When I am calling the 
client.GetStringAsync("?own=1").ContinueWith(task => { dataObjects = task.Result; }).Wait();

It is giving the following error '"UTF-8"' is not a supported encoding name.
Parameter name: name

Comment: Just posted edit that addresses the encoding issue. Hope that helps!